# How to display tables in separate lines

Tags: html, css

this is my html - click on the link below

http://wklej.org/id/658249/

I cannot edit this html. I have to edit is only through the CSS.

I would like to put every single box of the form in different line.
I cannot create any CSS code. I am stuck.

Comment: Well, if you can't edit html, and you can't create CSS, you're pretty stuck indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a `<table>` tag, browsers will generally just ignore the `<tr>`, `<td>`, and `<th>` tags, and just output the internal content. Ideally, you'd just change the html, but if you must do this in css, you can get them to line up by displaying the inputs/labels as block elements and then floating them appropriately:

```
#commentForm label, #commentForm input, #commentForm textarea { display: block; }
#commentForm label { float: left; clear: left; }
#commentForm input, #commentForm textarea { float: left; clear: right; }
#commentForm p { clear: both; }
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kY38D/2/

Comment: Could you please advice em how to make boxes ALIGN ? Your advice was very helpful but I need more help:). I am very appreciate.

Comment: @Art.py it gets messy but you can add a width: 10em to the #commentform label

Comment: Art.py, what @rene said. Here's an example jsfiddle with that update: http://jsfiddle.net/kY38D/3/

Answer (score 0):

As DRP96 said, since you have no table tag, you are not left with many options.. here is one way using widths:

```
<style>
    label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
    }

    input[type='text'], textarea {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 75%;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Then try `display:block` for tr. Usually it should be in different lines.

(You don't have any `table` tag)

Comment: This is the 21st century! We don't need no stinking table tags! :) Haha, woops, apparently we do. <tr> elements are getting annihilated.

Comment: Really? Cool @user1124318 which browser are you using?